# Return index of an element on 2d array Java

Tags: java

I have a 3 x 3 array `private int[][] board`

I want to get the index `[i][j]` as a integer representing the position of the element

For example

```
[0][0] = 0
[1][1] = 4  -- (middle spot)
[2][0] = 6 -- (last line, first item)
```

Is there an easy way instead of manually doing it for each position?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` and `%` operations can help you

```
int getByPosition(int[][] arr, int pos) {
    return arr[pos / arr.length][pos % arr.length];
}
```

**Update:** to get position by indexes:

```
int getPosByIndex(int[][] arr, int i, int j) {
    return arr.length * i + j;
}
```

Comment: That's how to convert a `pos` value into `i, j` pair. You should also show how to convert `i, j` pair into a `pos` value.